# VS 2022 MAUI, MSBuild tries to compile files for another platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, maui

I'm trying to write some platform specific code in a recently created MAUI App.

However, I'm faced with the following error:

> Error CS0117  'TestClass' does not contain a definition for 'HelloWindows'

MRE:

In a MAUI project, create a public class "TestClass" containing:

```
namespace MauiApp1;
public class TestClass
{
#if WINDOWS
    public static void HelloWindows()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("windows");
    }
#endif

#if ANDROID
    public static void HelloAndroid()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("android");
    }
# endif
}
```

In the folder `Platforms\Android` we'll create another class:

```
namespace MauiApp1;

public class AndroidPlatformSpecific
{
    public AndroidPlatformSpecific()
    {
        TestClass.HelloAndroid();
    }
}
```

And lastly, in `Platforms\Windows`:

```
namespace MauiApp1;

public class WindowsPlatformSpecific
{
    public WindowsPlatformSpecific()
    {
        TestClass.HelloWindows();
    }
}
```

I would expect this to compile. However, it does not.

What am I missing?

Repro repo: https://github.com/sidewinder94/MauiApp2

EDIT: I have found a workaround based on using partial classes.

However, I'd still like to either have a solution or a definitive explanation of *why* a preprocessor conditional compilation is not working as usual.

The reason behind that: static analysis tools will report the partial class that's in the `Platform\xxx` folder has a namespace that does not match its location.

EDIT2: Based on @Gerald Versluis's comment, and my previous try with partials this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/configure-multi-targeting?view=net-maui-7.0 allows to have platform specific partials in the same folder and namespace.

Comment: which platform do you have selected in VS?

Comment: The default MAUI selection, so : net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst;net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0

Comment: And please note, this is a *build* issue, Intellisense is working as expected (only shows the methods available for android in the android platform files, and same thing for windows)

Comment: Oh and just FYI: Tried to remove the build targets for ios / catalyst, and the error persists

Comment: Where are you calling `HelloWindows` from? Does that also have `#if WINDOWS` around it? Additionally, note that for Windows it's `#if WINDOWS` but for Android (and iOS, etc.) it's `#if __ANDROID__`

Comment: @GeraldVersluis That's in the question, there are 3 different classes. And as far as MAUI go, it seems to define both `ANDROID` and `__ANDROID__`

Comment: If the symbol was not defined for android the error would tell me that the missing method was `HelloAndroid`, not `HelloWindows` in the android specific file.

Comment: Whoops sorry, I missed that. Yeah that seems pretty weird and like it shouldn't happen. From first glance I can't see what is wrong with your code. If you wrap the call to HelloWindows in another `#if WINDOWS` it works you could use that to be unblocked maybe, but it shouldn't try to compile it in the first place

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Yeah, but then I'm going to have to propagate that `#if PLATFORM` all the way around, and I'd rather not.... This is an MRE, in my application I have quite a few files depending on that "common" class providing methods for several platforms. And the alternative : partials, seems to come with their own share of issues (in MAUI)

Comment: OK, so partials seem to work (1 partial in "common" area, then 1 per platform defining / implementing the methods specific to those platforms). Still think the preprocessor conditions should work....

Comment: The workaround I mentioned : https://github.com/sidewinder94/MauiApp2/commit/c1872d8b78bc8e2e38b83c869cb5d3b7a475b77f

Comment: Alternatively you could play with this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/configure-multi-targeting?view=net-maui-7.0

Shouldn't be necessary, but can help you out maybe

Comment: @GeraldVersluis That would allow to not have the issue of mismatching namespaces and file location, I'll give it a go.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Worked out, feel free to post this as an answer, if nobodies has an explanation on why preprocessor conditions did not work, I'll accept it.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, An alternative way of fixing this, that I have seen in similar situations, is to wrap the code in Windows folder with `#if Windows`, and the code in Android with `#if Android`. Try it. Obviously that should not be required, and indicates a multi-targetting bug. It feels like there are two passes or phases to source building, and the first phase "sees" platform-specific code that should be hidden from it. Its related to having code in the same (shared) namespace, in platform-specific folders.